# Entity framwerok - multithreaded inserting to one table- no read

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, asynchronous

```
 public void InsertPackagesProcessingLogs(IEnumerable<ProcessingLogInfo> logs)
    {
        using (var context = new MyContext()) // called on different thread
        {
            var packagesProcessingLogs = logs.Select(processingLog => new PackagesProcessingLog
            {
                SyncType =
                    context.SyncTypes.Include(type => type.PackagesProcessingLogs)
                        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.SyncTypeName.Equals(processingLog.SyncEntityType.ToString())),
                data = logs.ItsNotEntityModel.data
            });
            context.PackagesProcessingLogs.AddRange(packagesProcessingLogs);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

This is my method to save many rows in my table. I'm calling this in special Task

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                SynchronizationRepository.InsertPackagesProcessingLogs(logs));
```

Unfortunetely I got "Modified collection. You can not perform enumeration operation. ", because the timeout between the two calls was too short. How can I do this savier?

Comment: First, trying to write multiple rows concurrently causes *greater* delays due to conflicts. Second, ORMs and speed of insert are incompatible terms. If you want to insert rows fast, use SqlBulkCopy or whatever bulk import technologiy is available for your database. These will insert rows in the fastest way possible *and* reduce logging. Third, ORMs are meant to work with individual objects, not bulk data. They offer absolutely nothing in such scenarios except delays and complexity

Comment: Try changing the signature of the method from `public void InsertPackagesProcessingLogs(IEnumerable<ProcessingLogInfo> logs)` to something like list or array, e.g. `public void InsertPackagesProcessingLogs(List<ProcessingLogInfo> logs)`

Comment: @adamo94 how many rows are we talking about? Why do you think you need multithreading? If, for example you have a small number of rows (up to a few thousands) you should look to batching multiple INSERTs to a single statement and avoid the roundtrips. If you have many thousands, there is no alternative to bulk import tools

Comment: I have specific algorithm which should be as fast as possible. Moreover this process need logging some specific data so I'd like to do this in different task, beceause I dont want to slow down this main process. It's not necessary to save fast  this logs. It's only important to keep all logs.

Comment: try with `packagesProcessingLogs.ToList() `

Comment: Also I have made corrections. This List of objects which I send to repository it's not of entity model. It's some domain model and I do not know if it's important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue you're experiencing is elsewhere.

`Modified collection. You can not perform enumeration operation` is encountered when you're dealing with an `IEnumerable<>` that had it's underlying collection changed. This is likely because you're passing the same `IEnumerable<>` instance multiple times (multithreaded?).

`IEnumerable<>` becomes invalid the moment the underlying collection changes, so it's invalid for your case. Create materialized collections, e.g. `List<>` before you start modifying the underlying collection.